# How to change items color using Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, colors

I have to change the color of list items using array colors.

Elements to modify.

```
<ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">1</li>
      <li class="list__item">2</li>
      <li class="list__item">3</li>
</ul>
```

const colorArray = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];

I've tried to loop through list__items and then loop through colorArray and match item[currIndex].style.backgroundColor = colorArray[index] but every time got err.

If anyone can give me advice on how to solve it I will appreciate it.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">1</li> <!-- color red-- >
  <li class="list__item">2</li><!-- color yellow-- >
  <li class="list__item">3</li><!-- color blue-- >
</ul>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the desired color of a list item.

Loop through the items and set the color of each item to the saved color, something like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`ul.list li`)
  .forEach(li => li.style.color = li.dataset.color);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item" data-color="red">1 red</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-color="yellow">2 yellow</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-color="blue">3 blue</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By the time you've added an inline data-attribute you may as well have added an inline style

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement by using the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate over it to apply the styles.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const listItem = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');

const colorArray = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];

listItem.forEach((item, index) => item.style.color = colorArray[index]);
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">1</li>
  <li class="list__item">2</li>
  <li class="list__item">3</li>
</ul>
```